# Rails Dynamic 'Where' clause

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a search field where the user can enter "Param1" and  my controller contains:

```
Model.where('column_name LIKE ?', "%#{search_field}%")
```

This is converted to:

> ```sql
> SELECT ... FROM table WHERE column_name LIKE '%Param1%'
> ```

This works fine if the user enters "Param1" but I want make it comma separated search field.

So if the user enters "Param1,param2" or "Param1,Param2,Param3" the WHERE LIKE clause should work, My idea is to split the string based on ',' and have absolutely no idea on how to build the  Model.where clause here, since it can be 1 parameter or 4.

Answer (score 4):

In case you're using PostgreSQL, you can use ANY passing the mapped array of params:

```
Model.where('name LIKE ANY(array[?])', params.split(',').map { |val| "%#{val}%" })
# SELECT "models".*
# FROM "models"
# WHERE (name LIKE ANY(array['%param1%','%param2%']))
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what I do on one project:

```
values = search_field.split(',').map { |x| "%#{x}%" } # split values and add "%...%"
count = values.count # count them

# create an array of LIKE operators depending on the values counted
# if count is 2 then it will be an array: ['column_name LIKE ?', 'column_name LIKE ?']
where_sql_arr = count.times.map{'column_name LIKE ?'} 

# create the sql query joining with " OR "
# 'column_name LIKE ? OR column_name LIKE ?'
where_sql = where_sql_arr.join(' OR ') 

Model.where(where_sql, *values) # note the * before "values" to split the array into multiple arguments
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer uses the same method as the [answer of arieljuod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58124885/3982562), but uses the [Arel API](https://rubydoc.info/gems/arel/) instead of using plain strings.

```
values = search_field.split(',')
column_name = Model.arel_table[:column_name]
query = values.map { |value| column_name.matches("%#{value}%") }.reduce(:or)
Model.where(query)
```

Answer (score 1):

Splitting the parameters is a good idea.

`conditions = "Param1,Param2,Param3, Param4".gsub(" ","").split(',')`

If search without masks or regular expressions is enough, you can use `IN` query or AR:
`Model.where(column_name: conditions)`

Otherwise (at least in postgresql) the code becomes slightly more complicated.

Construct the query string from the input string:

`conditions = "Param1,Param2,Param3, Param4".gsub(" ","").split(',')`

`query = ("column_name ~* ? OR " * conditions.size)[0...-3] # Delete last unterminated " OR"`

And finally

`Model.where(query, *conditions) # splat operator (*) converts array into argument list`

Should work.

Comment: I believe this only works when I know the user is going to enter 3 parameters, what if he enters only 2?

Comment: This does not do multple LIKE queries, this will do an " column_name IN (...)" query which compares only equality.

Comment: @LutherSmi number of parameters can be arbitrary. The idea is to turn them into an array, which is accepted by the `Model.where(column_name: array)` and generates `column_name IN (...)` query. As @arieljuod noted, such a query only searches for exact matches. I added alternative solution (however, tested only in postgresql). Hope it helps